# Minimal number of edge-disjoint paths to cover a grid

Tags: graph-theory

Couldn't find an answer to the following question. Given the $5\times11$ grid, what is the minimal number of edge-disjoint paths to cover it? Here we assume that vertices may be repeated in a path while edges must be distinct. Obviously, we can use Euler's theorem but it's not clear how to do it.